# Load Hubspot Tracking Code Only On Pages Without a Login Form

Tags: javascript, wordpress, hubspot

I've searched the answer all over and can't seem to find it. I'm using Hubspot and hate the way their lead forms look, so I'm taking advantage of their "track non-Hubspot forms" feature. The problem on WordPress is that they track the login form for admin, which sends false leads to my client's Hubspot.

Because the tracking code is something I simply place in the header for all pages, I'm trying to find the right way to prevent tracking only on pages where the URL contains 'login' or 'admin'.

I tried using JS to check if the URL contains the above terms, but I am having trouble figuring out how to only add a script if the boolean is true. Code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" async defer>

//Statement is true if URL isn't a login or admin page
    if(!window.location.contains('login') && !window.location.contains('admin')) {

        <!-- Start of HubSpot Embed Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" id="hs-script-loader" async defer src="//js.hs-scripts.com/5562596.js"></script>
<!-- End of HubSpot Embed Code -->

    }

</script>
```

I realize now you can't have a script within a script. What I want is for the Hubspot script to only execute if the URL doesn't contain 'login' or 'admin' so we can avoid getting false lead form submissions in Hubspot. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can config this in your account of hubspot: option chatflow, section.
[add exclusions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVxgL.png)

This option works for me.